# What is the easiest way to move all data to a new MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, backup, restore, database-migration

I'm moving from 1 Server 2012 box to another Server 2012 box. I'm trying to move my SQL Server 2012 Express instance exactly (databases, logins, ect...) as it is, from 1 server to the other.

What is the easiest way to do this? I have just now realized my `.bak` backups do not restore the way I thought.

Here is my code to backup the databases.

```
REM @ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

REM Get date in format YYYY-MM-DD (assumes the locale is the United States)
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/ " %%A IN ('Date /T') DO SET NowDate=%%D-%%B-%%C

REM Build a list of databases to backup
SET DBList=%SystemDrive%SQLDBList.txt
SqlCmd -E -S LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS -h-1 -W -Q "SET NoCount ON; SELECT Name FROM master.dbo.sysDatabases WHERE [Name] NOT IN ('tempdb')" > "%DBList%"

REM Backup each database, prepending the date to the filename
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%I IN (%DBList%) DO (
ECHO Backing up database: %%I
SqlCmd -E -S LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [%%I] TO Disk='C:\SQLBackup\Database\MSSQL\%NowDate%_%%I.bak'"
ECHO.
)

REM Clean up the temp file
IF EXIST "%DBList%" DEL /F /Q "%DBList%"

ENDLOCAL
```

How do I restore the data back with this?

Comment: Have you scripted out your database users for deployment. You will need to grant them access once the backups are restored.

Comment: I have not. Ill see if I can find that kb

Comment: There is no easy script to backup/restore files. The backup part is usually pretty easy. The restore on the other hand is bit more trickier. When you restore on another server, the root path might not be at the same place so you will have to MOVE the datafiles at a different location. You also need to select which backup you use from your backupset file and if you need to restore log failes after that, you need to use no recovery. All these choices make scripting a nightmare to fill with parameters.

Comment: The backup/restore does a great job at backing up and restoring everything that's contained in the **databases** - tables, views, stored procedures etc. - but of course, it does **NOT** handle server-wide settings, like logins, permissions etc.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest db migration is detach/move file/attach but you must have copied the logins first.  You want to have the same uid to have them rebinded automatically. For that, you can use sp_help_revlogin (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992). This script will generated a login creation script you must run on the destination Server. Then you can use the Copy Database Wizard or manually detach them, copy the files then attach them at destination.